# Can I work as a photo assistant when entering the US under the terms of VWP?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, us-visa-waiver-program

I've got a question about ESTA and business travels.

I'm French, I'm living in Paris and working for a french company in digital retouch and digital assisting.

I'm paid in France in euro. I'm working into this company for a client, a French photographer, who he's gonna work in US for two days. Do I need a specific visa for that, or the ESTA is good enough?

Comment: Is your work connected with journalism?

Comment: Also probably important: if not journalism, what sort of work is the photographer doing, and what visa or other immigration status will he be using?

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to work in the US for two days?

Comment: @JonathanReez I think the question is whether this activity is allowed under B-1 status and therefore under the VWP.  The asker has not returned to the site since asking the question, so we're unlikely to get any clarification.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as unclear since the OP has failed to provide better information about his intentions in the US. While it would be a good question for this site if we had more details, as of now it would be a guessing game, based on opinions and/or interpretations of the OPs post and maybe too broad as such.