# I'm an employed cinematographer for a UK business, can i travel to the US to shoot videos on an ESTA?

Tags: visas, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, work

I've recently taken a new job as a cinematographer, employed full-time for a UK-based business. As part of my job I am required to travel to the US frequently to shoot commercials, interviews, mini-documentaries, etc.

I'm not certain yet, but I would estimate I will be visiting 6–12 times per year, all for this purpose. Most often trips would be 3–4 days but these may stretch as long as 2 weeks on longer productions.

As I'm paid by a UK company and wont be working for anyone else on these trips, am I okay to travel on the ESTA VWP program?

Is there anything else I need to be aware of when travelling? I understand my circumstances are quite unusual so just want to be sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I travel to the USA while working remotely for my non-US employer?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/12771/can-i-travel-to-the-usa-while-working-remotely-for-my-non-us-employer)

Comment: Expect to be scrutinized by immigration after your second or third visit.

Comment: does your employer have experience with sending film crew overseas? they should not be requiring you to figure this out imo

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. If you're working for "the media", you need a visa but I'm not sure exactly how "the media" is defined.

Comment: Not sure this is a real duplicate of @Traveller's suggestion. The previous question is about _working remotely_, whereas this one is about _working on-site_ with work that by its nature needs to be carried out in the US. That's a potentially pretty big difference from an immigration point of view. Different visas may be available or even required. In particular an [I visa](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/employment/visas-members-foreign-media-press-radio.html) would potentially be relevant here.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Indeed. There's the natural question of "If the company wants to film in the US, why don't they hire a US film crew?" and that makes a _huge_ difference to immigration issues.

Comment: @nkjt Not really. There is some experience in this for other reasons but not for the purpose of filming. Mainly for meetings. I'm not necessarily going to work this all out myself, just being pro-active and going to pass this onto the relevant people at my company as they are also unsure what the correct next steps are.

Comment: @DavidRicherby The company has had previous experience working with US based film crews on a freelance basis, but work has become so frequent that it made sense to create full time positions.

Comment: @TWilliams Sure. But the US would obviously rather those people were Americans, employed by American companies and paying US taxes. You don't need to justify your company's decisions to us but I'm bringing it up because it's the sort of thing I expect immigration officials to be very interested in.

Comment: @DavidRicherby okay, I understand now. Thanks. Do you believe that the Esta is suitable providing I am prepared with necessary proof or am I more likely to require a visa? I did also consider Global Entry as an alternative option, as I would explain my case once in interview rather than every time I visit.

Comment: @TWilliams I don't know enough to have an informed opinion about whether you'd need a visa. I have a good idea what the issues are but not how the different aspects weigh up in any particular case. But hopefully somebody will be able to post a proper answer.

Comment: Some infos https://dlgvisablog.com/blog/2014/3/7/special-considerations-for-film-and-television-visas It seems that in your case, ESTA is not valid, and I visa probably not either.

Comment: @DavidRicherby , it's incredibly common in the industry that filmmakers / crew travel around the world.

Comment: Man, just to be clear, you ARE NOT PRESS, right? If you're press, it's totally not permitted.

Comment: It's really foolish to close this, as someone with an actual job (film crew) is totally different from programmers.

Comment: hey @DavidRicherby - that's totally different man.  "film production" (making TV spots, episodic TV etc) is not Press.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/59790/can-i-work-as-a-photo-assistant-when-entering-the-us-under-the-terms-of-vwp

Comment: @Fattie No, not press or anything close. I create videos mainly exclusively for social media use within the clothing industry. Main reason for travel is because we have a select pool of 'influencers' that we work with on a repeat basis, and a lot of them are based in the US.

Comment: Sure thing, yeah you have nothing to do with "Press".  I think the best you can do is my answer - I hope it's clear!  I think the very short version is you could "get away with it" once or twice, but not monthly.  Bummer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I film corporate film on an ESTA?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/121789/can-i-film-corporate-film-on-an-esta)

Answer (score 7):

It's *probably a no* in your case.

It's a really tricky one and nobody knows the answer.

https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visa-waiver-program.html

The general idea is:

## You're allowed to come 'on business' but you're not allowed 'to work'.

This would have to be the most bent rule on the planet, though.

https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/123350/19233

Then there are people who try to push the envelope

[Work as freelancer while tourist in US for an already existing US client?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25416/work-as-freelancer-while-tourist-in-us-for-an-already-existing-us-client?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The tricky thing in your case is ...

## The damned cameras!

About 18 billion programmers waltz in to the US every day ("I'm just going for a meeting!") and then work their asses off. Who doesn't have a laptop?  It does not look "work-related".

But. In your case you'll show up with photo gear; your profession is just different. Due to the equipment to begin with.

Say you were (honest to God) going only to have a production meeting about a project. That is 100% bona fide.  You would just be "doing business".  But if you're scouting?  Tricky.  Actually shooting?  You're then like the tidal wave of programers who fly to the states ("just a meeting!") and then in reality work their asses off.

As a factual matter I can think of 5? folks known to me who've done this over the years and it's a total non-issue.

But in your case you're doing it repetitively - pretty much every month.

I really just don't know how that plays out.

My guess is probably "No" unfortunately.

Unfortunately this is a couple yrs old:

https://dlgvisablog.com/blog/o-visas-for-the-film-and-tv-industry

Comment: sorry!  @audionuma already posted that link in a comment.

Comment: Just wanted to add this link, which discusses a tailor who arrived in the US on a B1 for the purpose of taking measurements of customers for suits. Could be contrasted with the videographer so long as they do not intend to sell the footage within the US, interesting read http://myattorneyusa.com/understanding-permissible-b1-business-activities-through-matter-of-hira

Comment: wow @Steve - amazing law from 60 years ago !!!

Comment: How would you come "on business" _without_ working on something?